# Remove item from json and edit remaining items - nodejs/firebase function

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

So I'm trying to update a json, after deleting an item using firebase `.delete()`.

This is the `json` before delete

```
"data": [
    {
        "position": "3",
        "name": "foo"
    },
    {
        "name": "bar",
        "position": "1"
    },
    {
        "name": "deleteMe",
        "position": "2"
    },
    {
        "name": "somethingElse",
        "position": "4"
    }
]
```

and this is after:

```
"data": [
    {
        "position": "3",
        "name": "foo"
    },
    {
        "name": "bar",
        "position": "1"
    },
    {
        "name": "somethingElse",
        "position": "4"
    }
]
```

now all I have to do is reorder `foo` and `somethingElse` items positions from `#3` to `#2` and `#4` to `#3`.
How can I do this?

EDIT:
This is the output I want:

```
"data": [
    {
        "position": "2",
        "name": "foo"
    },
    {
        "name": "bar",
        "position": "1"
    },
    {
        "name": "somethingElse",
        "position": "3"
    }
]
```

Comment: If the purpose of `position` is only to indicate the order of the element, you don't need it. Either use an array index or use a Set/Map if appropriate (no duplicates).

Comment: I'm not clear on what you want your final output to be. Could you give the example of what your final object should look like?

Comment: Sorry I'm adding it right now

Comment: There is not sorting that would do this. You would have to be aware of every possible `name` in order to put them in the order you want. Alpha and Numberic sorting won't work when you want "foo" before "bar" AND "somethingElse" after "bar."

Comment: I'm just trying to edit `position` to be in order, without editing `name`

Comment: Can you explain your actual constraints in more details ? For example : your `position` fields are numbers stored as strings, and, as you display it, the index of an element in the array is not the same as its `position` field. Can you store `position` as an actual number ? can you reorder the elements in the array, so that `1` comes before `2` comes before `3` ?

Comment: I need the position because frontend needs it to put items in order when displaying. I can sort it, yes, but I need `position` to be in order like `1,2,3,4,5...` not `1,2,4,5...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Array.prototype.map`

```js
var obj = {
  data: [
    {
      position: "2",
      name: "foo"
    },
    {
      name: "bar",
      position: "1"
    },
    {
      name: "somethingElse",
      position: "3"
    }
  ]
};
var output = 
  obj.data.map((o, i) => {
    o["position"] = "" + (i + 1);
    return o;
  });
console.log(output);
```